# Using JQuery to access/propagate selectors to new input fields after a dynamic page change that doesn't involve a full page refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-selectors

I have a jQuery selector that is run after a user changes the name of the country in an input form.  However, after the country field changes the address input fields change and the page is refreshed dynamically without a full page reload.

Question:  How do I have JQuery access/propagate selectors to new input fields after a inline/partial page refresh?

Example:

```
jQuery('[id^="Country"]').on('mouseup', function(e) {
// code gets here okay... the problem is it doesn't call the the following after the page refresh... 
});

jQuery('select[id^="AccountEditForm.Parent Ship To Address."]:visible,input[id^="AccountEditForm.Parent Ship To Address."]:visible').on('mousedown', function(e) {
// code no longer gets here because the input fields are updated dynamically for some reason
});
```

NOTE: I was using .live()... but this is not supported any longer by the newer versions of jQuery.

V$H.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).on('mouseup', '[id^="Country"]',  function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
​});​
```

[Exmple](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/WSe3n/)

```
for(i=1;i<6;i++)
{
    var div=$("<div id='Country"+i+"'>country"+i+"</div>");
    $('#wrapper').append(div);
}

$('#wrapper').on('mouseup', '[id^="Country"]', function(e){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/WSe3n/3/)